# touchesBegan and touchesMoved also called during pinch

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a pinch gesture and a pan gesture in a view. I am also using touchesBegan and touchesMoved method. Surprisingly when i am pinching my view it is sometimes also calling touchesBegan and touchesMoved.How to stop calling this methods during pinching? Here is what i did.

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if let touchCount = event?.touches(for: self)?.count {
            if touchCount == 1 {
                // Doing some task
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        if let touchCount = event?.touches(for: self)?.count {
            if touchCount == 1 {
                // Doing some task
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my ViewController: I created a customView object of CustomView class and added some gestures like below:

```
let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinch(recognizer:)))
customView.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)    
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(recognizer:)))
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
self.customView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` are really, really generic -- *whenever* your finger touches down or moves, they'll be called. This includes button presses and just pretty much every thing that your finger can touch.

So if you're using gesture recognizers for pan and pinch, stick with gesture recognizers. Use an `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of relying on `touchesBegan`, and another `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for `touchesMoved`.

Comment: But i used only pangesture. In panGesture you can check state either it is begin or changed or ended.